# how to create multiple instances of a class?

Tags: java, arraylist, sortedlist

I have a class Borrower which consists of a name and then it also stores an arraylist full of items that the person has borrowed.

I want to be able to create multiple instances of this class from my main and then be able to access them to view the items they have borrowed.

I am having trouble understanding how to create multiple instances. I just keep running into the issue of overwriting the the Borrowed class.

So in the code below if I create newBorrower("Tim") and then addItem("Wrench"), and then go to create newBorrower("john") then I overwrite newBorrower.

I want to be able to create multiple instances of Borrower based on user input?

I've tried saving the entire Borrower class. I'm not sure if that would work, because it will not sort so I can't add multiple names or I get an error.

Borrower Class

```
public class Borrower 
{

    protected String name;
    protected String item;

    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Borrower()
    { 
    }

    public Borrower(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void addItem(String item)
    {
        this.item = item;
        itemList.add(item);
    }
```

Main Class

```
public class WhoBorrowedIt 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArraySortedList<String> borrowersList = new ArraySortedList<String>();
        Borrower newBorrower = new Borrower();
        Borrower otherBorrower = new Borrower();

        Scanner inName = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inItem = new Scanner(System.in);

        String item;
        String name;

        String menu;
        int option;

        menu = "Make a selection: " + "\n" 
                + "1. Add Borrower" + "\n"
                + "2. Add Item Borrowed" + "\n"
                + "3. Remove Item Returned" + "\n"
                + "4. View Borrowers" + "\n"
                + "5. Exit";

        do
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(menu);
            option = in.nextInt();

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1: //create borrower
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter Name");
                    name = inName.nextLine();
                    newBorrower = new Borrower(name);
                    borrowersList.add(newBorrower.getName());
                    break;
                }

                case 2: //add items
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter item");
                    item = inItem.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Who is borrowing");
                    name = inName.nextLine();
                    if(borrowersList.contains(name))
                    {
                        newBorrower.addItem(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newBorrower = new Borrower(name);
                        borrowersList.add(newBorrower.getName());
                        newBorrower.addItem(item);
                    }
                }
        }while(option != 5)
}
}
```

Comment: Time to find out what an *array* is.

Comment: Instead of keeping an `List` of borrower names, you can keep keep a `List` of `Borrower` objects.  So when you ask who is borrowing something, you get that borrower object first (from the list) and add the item to its `itemList` - does that help?

Comment: Actually, a Map of Borrowers might be more appropriate.  Then each borrower can be inserted into the Map by name.

Comment: @HotLicks maybe a `Map` - by name.

Comment: You've already got the mechanism down for creating multiple borrowers. It's inside your Borrower class. Examine how you handle a borrower borrowing multiple items. Do something similar to that for borrowers. Basically, borrow from the borrowers class to store the borrowers borrowing.

Comment: I tried making my list a list of Borrowers, but it wouldn't sort. I was able to do it with the unsorted list and that worked ok, but it looks like the Map is the best option and now that I have an idea of what I am doing with that it worked out real well.

Comment: @twjohns29 It's easy to make it sortable, make Borrowers implement Comparable and then add in compareTo()

Comment: CBredlow, Thanks for the advise. That makes sense. I thought maybe Comparable only worked on strings or something because it worked if i just added the name as a string to the list, but that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Map` like this

```
if (borrowersMap.containsKey(name))
{
    borrowersMap.get(name).addItem(item)
}
else
{
    newBorrower = new Borrower(name);
    borrowersMap.put(newBorrower.getName(), newBorrower);
    newBorrower.addItem(item);
}
```

where `borrowersMap` is a HashMap

```
Map<String, Borrower> borrowersMap = new HashMap<String, Borrower>();
```

Comment: A `TreeMap` would automatically sort by key.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your list to this

```
List<Borrower> borrowerList = new ArraySortedList<Borrower>();
```

and then add a method to your program that gets a borrower by name

```
private Borrower getBorrowerByName( String borrowerName ){
    for( Borrower borrower : borrowerList ){
        if( borrower.getName().equalsIgnoreCase( borrowerName ) ){
            return borrower;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

then when you create a new borrower, you add it to the list - when you get an existing borrower, you use the method and check for `null` before adding an item to it.

Comment: This is like a `Map` but both slower and less user-friendly.

Comment: fair comment, I was only trying to keep the existing structure as the OP was using (as it is obvious that he is newish to the Java world).  Introducing better structures/objects to accomplish the task, while obvious for old hats in Java, may make things more complicated to new learners unnecessarily.  Oh, and I disagree with being less-user friendly but it's a matter of opinion I suppose.